# dc.js apply some, but not all chart selections to numberDisplay, while maintaining the interactions between charts in place

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset (*data*) with the following row/column structure:

```
Date        Category1      Category2       Revenue
30/12/2014  a              x               10    
30/12/2014  b              x               15
31/12/2014  a              x               11
1/1/2015    a              x               13
2/1/2015    a              x               14
2/1/2015    b              x                9
2/1/2015    c              z                4
...
```

Based on *data* I create a couple of dimensions and groups:

```
var ndx                 = crossfilter(data);
var cat1Dim             = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Category1;});
var revenuePerCat1      = cat1Dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Revenue; });
var cat2Dim             = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Category2;});
var revenuePerCat2      = cat2Dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Revenue; });
var dateDim             = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Date; });
var revenuePerDate      = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Revenue; });
```

Next, I create the following charts:

1. a line chart; dimension = dateDim, group = revenuePerDate
2. a pie-chart; dimension = cat1Dim, group = revenuePerCat1
3. a pie-chart; dimension = cat2Dim, group = revenuePerCat2

Besides the charts I would also like to show the year-to-date value of the revenues via a numberDisplay. Initially I thought to achieve this by adding a simple if condition to the reduceSum function where I reduce the data to contain only items of the current year, like so:

```
var ytdRev = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { if(d.Date.getFullYear() == curYear) {return d.Revenue;} else{return 0;}});
```

A box containing a numberDisplay item is then called by:

```
box_ytd
    .formatNumber("$,.4s")
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return Math.round(d * 1000) / 1000; })
    .group(ytdRev);
```

This works perfectly fine if one selects one of the categories displayed in the pie-charts, but is incorrect when one also starts to filter date ranges in the line chart. Namely, instead of a year-to-date value, actually a 'date-to-date' value for the specific selection will be returned. Although this behaviour is correct from a technical perspective, I would like to know how I can instruct dc.js such that it will only take into account chart selections from a certain set of charts when rendering a numberDisplay. The selections made in the pie-charts should, however, both update the displayed selection in the line chart and the numberDisplay.
Ideally, I would like to use one crossfilter instance only, but I am open to any suggestions that involve a second crossfilter as well.

**EDIT:**

Based on Gordon's comment I played around with a custom reduce function. Instead of ndx.groupAll() I applied the following reduce function with a .groupAll() on the dimension level:

```
function reduceAdd(p,v) {
    if(v.Date.getFullYear() == curYear)
    p.revenue += +v.Revenue;
    return p;}
function reduceRemove(p,v) {
    if v.Date.getFullYear() == curYear)
    p.revenue -= +v.Revenue;
    return p;}
function reduceInitial() {
    return {revenue:0 };}

var ytdRev = dateDim.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
```

The .valueAccessor in the numberDisplay is changed from d.value.revenue to d.revenue:

```
box_ytd
    .formatNumber("$,.4s")
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return Math.round(d.revenue * 1000) / 1000; })
    .group(ytdRev);
```

The numberDisplay will now reflect the total value for the current year for each of the selections made in the pie-charts. Date selections will only affect the pie-charts' values; the numberDisplay shares the same dimension with the line chart and hence the numberDisplay is unaffected by any selections on that dimension.

Comment: If you just want to ignore the filters from one chart, you could put your custom group on the same dimension as that chart (and use a custom reduce instead of a group all). If you want to ignore multiple dimensions, I don't think it can be done without using another crossfilter.

Comment: Based on your comments I edited the original post with a working solution. Works perfectly for a single numberDisplay, thanks for your suggestion! I played around with the option of a second crossfilter as well; in case you push the filters from the charts of the first crossfilter to the second, one can achieve the same result. Since I only employ this for a single numberDisplay, your first suggestion is much more efficient.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works. Thanks for posting your solution, as I'm sure it will help others.

Comment: Could you please make an answer out of your solution so others know that this question has been answered?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gordon's comment I played around with a custom reduce function. Instead of ndx.groupAll() I applied the following reduce function with a .groupAll() on the dimension level:

```
function reduceAdd(p,v) {
    if(v.Date.getFullYear() == curYear)
    p.revenue += +v.Revenue;
    return p;}
function reduceRemove(p,v) {
    if v.Date.getFullYear() == curYear)
    p.revenue -= +v.Revenue;
    return p;}
function reduceInitial() {
    return {revenue:0 };}

var ytdRev = dateDim.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
```

The .valueAccessor in the numberDisplay is changed from d.value.revenue to d.revenue:

```
box_ytd
    .formatNumber("$,.4s")
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return Math.round(d.revenue * 1000) / 1000; })
    .group(ytdRev);
```

The numberDisplay will now reflect the total value for the current year for each of the selections made in the pie-charts. Date selections will only affect the pie-charts' values; the numberDisplay shares the same dimension with the line chart and hence the numberDisplay is unaffected by any selections on that dimension.